# Cygnus 0.8.2 doesn't work

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I have installed Cygnus 0.8.2 in a VM with CentOS-6.5-x64. 
In the config file agent.conf I only change the following:

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = xxxxxx
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = myuser
```

I run cygnus with this command:

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

But when I send a xml message occurs this error:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,133 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:163)] The event TTL has expired, it is no more re-injected in the channel (id=617320308, ttl=0)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,133 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:193)] Finishing transaction (1437651766-108-0000000000)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,637 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:128)] Event got from the channel (id=617320308, headers={timestamp=1437651946136, content-type=application/xml, transactionId=1437651766-108-0000000000, fiware-service=def_serv, fiware-servicepath=def_servpath, ttl=0, destination=sensorreading1_sensorreading}, bodyLength=891)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,643 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink.persist(OrionHDFSSink.java:356)] [hdfs-sink] Persisting data at OrionHDFSSink. HDFS file (def_serv/def_servpath/sensorreading1_sensorreading/sensorreading1_sensorreading.txt), Data ({"recvTime":"2015-07-23T11:45:46.136Z","nodeid":"1", "nodeid_md":[],"sensorid":"1", "sensorid_md":[],"systemid":"1", "systemid_md":[],"value":"-990.6", "value_md":[]})
2015-07-23 14:46:02,644 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:143)] Persistence error (The /user/cristina.albaladejo/def_serv/def_servpath/sensorreading1_sensorreading directory could not be created in HDFS. HttpFS response: 503 Service unavailable)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,644 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:163)] The event TTL has expired, it is no more re-injected in the channel (id=617320308, ttl=0)
2015-07-23 14:46:02,644 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:193)] Finishing transaction (1437651766-108-0000000000)
```

Then, data are not stored in HDFS... How I can solve this?

The complete config is:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink mysql-sink ckan-sink
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel mysql-channel ckan-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel mysql-channel ckan-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# OrionHDFSSink configuration
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = x1.y1.z1.w1,x2.y2.z2.w2
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = cristina.albaladejo
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = MYTOKEN
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = x.y.z.w
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth = false
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_user = krb5_username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_password = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_login_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5_login.conf
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5.conf

cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: I will need you edit the question and paste the complete configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I have already edited the question with the configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not configured the following properties (putting the required values):

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
```

In addition, since you are only configuring the HDFS persistence, avoid any reference to `mysql-sink` and `ckan-sink`, i.e.:

```
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
```

Try with the proposed changes and let me know if it works.